# S3 -> CloudFront -> Client with (Gzip + Etag)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, compression, etag

Is there any way to distribute JS Lib from AWS CloudFront with ETag header (for caching control) and with Compression (only for clients that support it) using S3 as origin?

As I understand I can:
1) Upload JS Lib (uncompressed) on S3, enable auto compression on CloudFront
- but I lose ETag header, in this case, that means I lose ability to update quickly JS Lib on the client side

2) Upload JS Lib (already compressed) on S3:
- but I lose clients that do not support compression

3) Use own Origin instead of S3 and control compression by myself:
- I lose S3's hight durability and I have setup and manage Origin by myself

Is there 4th way that would not have disadvantages that I described above?

Comment: Why would you lose the ETag in option 1?

Comment: CloudFront removes it: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html - `If you configure CloudFront to compress content, CloudFront removes the ETag response header from the files that it compresses.`

Comment: So it does -- confirmed through testing. Strange, since they could have just [weakened](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag#Strong_and_weak_validation) the ETag (though I'm not sure that would have helped you). So, the next question would be whether `If-Modified-Since` isn't viable/sufficient, and the question after that would be whether you *really* care about the tiny set of browsers that doesn't understand gzip content encoding. (Me? I don't.) I think there will be a workaround once Lambda@Edge becomes available, but I hesitate to suggest it, now, since we don't know when that may be.